# Can I use gulp to insert content from a file into another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have an index.html and a header.html.  What I would like to do is to have a gulp task that takes the text from the header.html and inserts it into the index.html. So for example:

header.html

```
abcdef
ghijkl
```

index.html  before insertion

```
line1
line2
<!-- header:start -->
...
...
...
<!-- header:end -->
line3
```

index.html  after insertion

```
line1
line2
<!-- header:start -->
abcdef
ghijkl
<!-- header:end -->
line3
line4
```

Can anyone help me and give me some advice how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your after is definitely achievable. The quickest and easiest is probably to use a well known tempting solution like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mustache & http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

which would look something like

src/routes/index.html

```
<html>
{{> ../partials/head.html }}
</html>
```

src/partials/head.html

```
<head>
  <link .... />
  <somethingelse>
</head>
```

gulp file

```
gulp.src("./src/routes/*.html")
    .pipe(mustache()).pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
```

should hopefully produce

dist/index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link .... />
    <somethingelse>
  </head>
</html>
```

although i have not tried these snippets exactly, i think it should convey the ideas :)

to do with pure JS & gulp would also be possible, it would probably require a custom stream processor and some sort of search replace etc. but unless you have a reason not to use external dependencies i would suggest the tempting library approach as you will install gain much more functionality (looping, etc )